# esxi 5 VMKernel and linux driver compatability mode

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, linux-kernel

Many peoples around the web say, the esxi 5 kernel isn't based on linux kernel, but in the same times they say "ESX(i) includes a Linux driver compatability mode (drivers still have to be compiled specifically for ESXi)", so my simple question is, if this vmkernel isn't based on linux kernel, how can i do to porting a linux driver to esxi 5 kernel

I downloaded the megaraid source code driver for esxi 5 and in this file megaraid_sas.c i saw this

```
*  Send feedback to: <megaraidlinux@lsi.com>
*
*  Mail to: LSI Corporation, 1621 Barber Lane, Milpitas, CA 95035
*     ATTN: Linuxraid
*/

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/uio.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/div64.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/compat.h>
#include <linux/blkdev.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#if defined(__VMKLNX__)
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <scsi/scsi_tcq.h>
#include "vmklinux_scsi.h"
#endif
#include <linux/poll.h>
#include <scsi/scsi.h>
#include <scsi/scsi_cmnd.h>
#include <scsi/scsi_device.h>
#include <scsi/scsi_host.h>
```

If i understood, the vmkernel isn't based on linux kernel, but it use the linux kernel header

Comment: Please don't do this, it's a seriously bad idea - the great thing about ESXi is that if you stick to hardware from the HCL it can be very stable indeed - undermining that is unnecessary, dangerous and marks you out an unprofessional.

Comment: @Chopper3 Or a hobbyist... But yes, this is not the intended use of the platform.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the question here...

The VMware kernel is NOT Linux... You DO see a modified Busybox user land, though. In addition, much of the core driver support is derived from the existing Linux driver base.

Comment: my question is, if the vmkernel isn't based on linux kernel, how can port a linux driver to esxi 5 kernel?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The ESXi supported hardware lost is intentionally small, but easy to comply with if you're using decent server hardware. What hardware are you trying to add driver support for?

Comment: i don't want to write or add a driver to esxi, i just wanna know how to do that and why is possible make a porting of linux driver to esxi kernel, i saw the vmkernel is based on SimoS, i would like to have some clear information about the linux driver porting to esxi kernel